# .NET Google auth, why we cannot have it without cookies?

Tags: .net, oauth, authorization, google-oauth

Sorry, I asked everybody around, but no clear answer. I'm investigating how auth works in .NET. And I saw that in **ALL** examples `AddGoogle()`, `AddFacebook()`, any RemoteAuthentication is accompanied with `.AddCookies()`.

If you don't add `.AddCookies()` you will simply get this error: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/RemoteAuthenticationOptions.cs#L38

[image]

The one thing I'm wondering is why?

The answer could be that "we cannot sign in" using google cookies and google tokens (OAuth), so we are using our ones. But, we have `.AddJwtBearer()` that also cannot sign in the request, but it CAN be used without `.AddCookies()`. I was comparing JwtBearerHandler and GoogleHandler from the source code, and I do not see any difference that tells me, why we cannot use GoogleAuth without our own cookies.

What prevents the team that developed remote authorization & authentication for .NET to emit OAuth flow on each [Authorize] protected endpoint in .NET api?

Sorry for that question, asked all mature colleagues, investigated source code, but no luck(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Firstly I think it is Authorization not Authentication. Which tokens do you mean by Access Tokens or refresh tokens? It is better way to have our own JWT so that we can have Authorizations/Roles attached with JWT. Can you re work on question for clear understanding so I give my two cents?

Comment: @arjunthota,
Okay, it is authorization in the backend side where we are using Google auth, and it is Authorization & Authentication in Google, because to make OAuth authorization code flow - authorization server will authenticate the Resource Owner.
Sorry, I'm not talking about better approach. I would like to know why it is done in the way, that we cannot use Google auth without .net cookies.
Btw, reworked question a little, thank you for suggestion